# How to dynamically rebind JQuery Objects

Tags: jquery, events, caching, object, dynamic-rebinding

I am making a module for the Joomla! page of a client that uses Ajax to render different queries to the database. The result of these queries is that I regenerate the entire HTML code of the different DIVs. Within my jQuery Object I have a  function named as `cache()` that stores all objects that I need to attach them the different events. My problem is that every time I regenerate the HTML code from any of these divs, I have to rebuild all the objects, so I've created a new function `recache()` to make this work more easy.

I guess this is not the best procedure.
Is there any way to keep alive these handlers without having to call this function `cache()` each time, or is there any way to rebind dynamically this objects?

Thank you!

Here my code:

```
    var Object = {
        init: function() {
            this.cache();
            this.bindEvents();
            return this;
        },

        cache: function() {
                   OBJECTS....
                       this.nameObject = $('#anchor');
                       etc..
        },

        recache: function() {
            Objects to be recached as needed.
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            EVENTS attached to the objects. 
                        this.nameObject.on( 'click', 'context', this.nameFunction );

        },

                    nameFunction: function() {
                        #CODE....
                    }

                }; //END Playlist (Object)

window.Object = Object.init();
```

I usually use `on()` function instead of `delegate()`, `live()` or `bind()`, butI'm not sure this is exactly my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You hinted at the right plan: use `.on()`. Remember though that when you're delegating a listener, you need to delegate to a listener that will not be destroyed.

Or in other words:

```
// will not do anything useful for this scenario:
$('.something').on('click', function() { /* ... */ });
```

is different from

```
// use the document as a listener: will work but not efficient
$(document).on('click', '.something', function() { /* ... */ });
```

which is different from

```
// use a closer ancestor that is NOT destroyed. Best option if you can
$('#someAncestor').on('click', '.something', function() { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: Upps! We're so sorry, you're right! Exactly the context of the on() method of the functions in question are destroyed when I regenerate the HTML code. This is the reason of having to recache these objects. I'm feel like a newbie. ;) ;) THANKS!!

Comment: Cool beans. I only mention this because you're new to SO, but if this answer helped, you can "accept" it with the checkbox icon to the left, once a certain amount of time has passed (15min? can't remember)

Comment: Finally I refactored my application changing all the events to the ancestors, and except for some minor problems with Safari also solved, all works like a charm now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Bind the event handler on a parent element and use event delegation to handle the events. By binding the event handler on a parent element you don't need to bind it on all the child elements.

/**HTML**/

```
<div id="container">
    <button id="button1" class="click">button with click</button>
    <button id="button2" class="click">button with click</button>
</div>
```

/**Javascript**/

```
// use this
$("#container").on("click", ".click", function(){
    alert(this.id + ": I've been clicked.");
});

// don't use this
$(".click").on("click", function(){
    alert(this.id + ": I've been clicked.");
});
```