# how to make jquery functions work with dynamically changing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

first let me say i have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954932/difference-between-jquery-click-bind-live-delegate-trigger-and-on).

which says (as  does [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) that the `.live()` and `.on()` let you assign a jquery event, which applies even to future elements. however my following jquery:

```
    $("#playerImg").on("mouseenter",function () {
        console.log("works");});
```

works at the start but after i run this code:

```
function move(moveTo) {
   document.getElementById(player.currentLocation).innerHTML = "";
      player.currentLocation = moveTo;
   document.getElementById(player.currentLocation).innerHTML += player.displayText;
}
```

here are relevant variables

```
var player = {
    "displayText" : "<img src = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kAhN0HX-MBk/T_5bApfhbJI/AAAAAAAAAuI/lUww8xT9yV8/s1600/smileys_001_01.png'" +
        id='playerImg' "class='onTop' alt='you' border='0' />",

   "currentLocation": 0 //(i use a 5 * 5 table with id's 0-24)
}
```

the above code doesnt run. how can i make an event in jquery, which can run on elements that dont exist yet?

[link here](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/adventure.html)

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944499/how-to-dynamically-rebind-jquery-objects  Hope that helps.

Comment: You're using a direct event, and you need to use a delegated event, meaning you attach to a container that contains whatever you actually want to attach the handler to.  See the [Direct and delegated events section](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for on()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `.on()` like you do apply direct event, which are faster but **DOESN'T** apply to dynamic elements.

You need to use `.on()` like that for dynamic elements :

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", '#playerImg',function () {
    console.log("works");
});
```

`document` should be the closest static element for performance gain.

Side note, `id`'s must be unique, change it for `class`. The code above may not work because it use an id. If it's the case and you don't want to change for whatever reason, use this :

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", 'img#playerImg',function () {
    console.log("works");
});
```

Comment: Nice catch about reusing id's . . . should probably be a class, instead of an id.

Comment: i know the id thing, is it still a problem if the 2 of them never exist at the same time?

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight It is okay if they never exist at the same time.

Comment: and does `$(document).on(trigger, element,function () {` work for any type of jquery event?

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight yes it does!

Comment: well as you see i clear the first `<img>` b4 i write the second.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight to be honnest, i didnt really analise your code, i saw your misstake on the first block of text ;)

Comment: still you gave me exactly what i was looking for my program now runs exactly how i want it

Comment: thanks again do you think you can answer this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556120/jquery-issue-with-dynamicaly-selected-elements